# Cloning from Github to a specific directory results in an empty directory. Where are the files?

Tags: git, github

Using Windows 8.1 I am trying to clone a repository to my local drive using the following commands

```
cd hardware
mkdir esp8266com
cd esp8266com
git clone https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino.git .
```

The directory `hardware` exists. When I run the clone command it tells me that there is already stuff there even though I just created the directory `esp8266com` and have verified that there are no files in it, hidden or otherwise.

I then ran a `Git Pull` in the directory to see if I could pull the repository. I get the following response, which looks like it is getting the files.

```
remote: Counting objects: 7644, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Total 7644 (delta 41), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 7547
Receiving objects: 100% (7644/7644), 11.33 MiB | 1.30 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4288/4288), done.
From https://github.com/esp8266/arduino
* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

When I view the directory with the `Git Gui` it shows that everything was pulled but there are no files in the directory. I've even done a search on the complete drive and can not find them.

Where are these files? What am I missing?

******* Solution
The answer marked below was the correct syntax. 
The thing that was causing the problems was that I was not opening the command prompt as admin so even the commands seemed to work they actually did not write any files because of permissions.

Comment: That last paragraph should probably be a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the trailing `.` you can just do

```
cd esp8266com
git clone https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino.git
```

and that should do it,  `git-pull` is only used to synch and since there hasn't been a .git repo created on your system the files would be loaded in a temp dir and discarded after the the synch failed.

Comment: That gives me an error `fatal: destination path 'arduino' already exists and is not an empty directory.` Even though there is nothing in that directory.

Comment: @JohnS it's probablty created the directory inside esp8266com, just remove the dir and you should be good to go.